# Unable to show MySql Record in hbs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, crud

i am trying to show MySql Record on my hbs Page with nodejs neither getting any error nor result.
i am using express generator, i am in programing after a long time i am done with inserting data in MySsql table my next step is showing data on hbs page that i gave up now i need your help guys let me know where is problem in my code?
Thanks.

**index.js**

```
const { response } = require('express');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql = require('mysql')

//SQL connection
var conn = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'MyDatabaseforMyProjects@',
  database: 'crud_db'
})
conn.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log('Connected to MySQL..')

})


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});

// create page route
router.get('/create', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('create');
  console.log(req.body)
});

// create page route
router.post('/create', function(req, res, next) {
  
  let data = {
    first_name: req.body.first_name,
    last_name: req.body.last_name,
    email : req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    phone: req.body.phone,
  };
 conn.query(`INSERT INTO user_form set ?`, [data], function(err, result){
   if(err) {console.log(err)}
   else{
      return res.redirect('/');
   } 
 } )
});

// this script to fetch data from MySQL databse table
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  conn.query('SELECT * FROM user_form', function (err, result, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  
//  return res.redirect('/');
});
});


module.exports = router;
```

**index.hbs**

```
<h3 class="text-center border border-light p-5 container col-sm-5">User's Record</h3>

<div class=" container col-sm-6"> Click <a href="/create">here</a> to Register user</div>

<table class="table container col-sm-8">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First name</th>
      <th scope="col">Last name</th>
      <th scope="col">Email</th>
      <th scope="col">Password</th>
      <th scope="col">Phone</th>
      <th scope="col">Action</th>
    </tr>

  <tbody>
         {{#each }}
        <tr>
          <td scope="col">{{ id }}</td>
          <td scope="col">{{ first_name }}</td>
          <td scope="col">{{ last_name }}</td>
          <td scope="col">{{ email }}</td>
          <td scope="col">{{ password }}</td>
          <td scope="col">{{ phone }}</td>

          
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
      </tbody>
 
  
  </thead>
```